# Backbone.js: Table not presenting correcting with templates

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have 3 separate templates, one for the head of a table the other for contents and the third for the closing tags. When I created the hole table and place it into a template altogether it looks like so:

[image]

But when I split it into three templates I get the following:

[image]

The table never forms correctly and the body of the table seem to ignore the head of the table. and never spreads out. If I remove the head template the body dosent change.

**Here is the code :**

**AbsenceList.js**

```
window.AbsenceListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.template1 = _.template(tpl.get('tableEnd'));
        this.template2 = _.template(tpl.get('tableStart'));
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        var self = this;
        this.model.bind("add", function(absence) {
            $(self.el).append(new AbsenceListItemView({
                model: absence
            }).render().el);
        });
    },
    render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template2());
        _.each(this.model.models, function(absence) {
            $(this.el).append(new AbsenceListItemView({
                model: absence
            }).render().el);
        }, this);
        $(this.el).append(this.template1());
        return this;
    }
});
window.AbsenceListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('absence-table_1'));
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },
    render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

**tableStart.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="example-default">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Fridays</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

**TableEnd.html**

```
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

**AbsenceTable.html**

```
<tr><td><a href='#student/<%= studentidStudent %>'>  <button>Link</button></a></td>

<td><% if (monday == true) { %> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><%} else if (monday == false) { %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><%} %></td>
<td><% if (tuesday == true) { %> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><%} else if (tuesday == false) { %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><%} %></td>
<td><% if (wednesday == true) { %> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><%} else if (wednesday == false) { %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><%} %></td>
<td><% if (thursday == true) { %> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><%} else if (thursday == false) { %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><%} %></td>  
<td><% if (friday == true) { %> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><%} else if (friday == false) { %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><%} %></td>

</tr>
```

What is the reason for the body of the table not aligning with the head ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is not a simple text concatenation. If you give a string, it will convert that string to a set of DOM nodes and insert those nodes. If you give `append` a string that contains invalid HTML, then the browser will do its best to fix your HTML before it adds any nodes to the DOM.

You're adding this "HTML":

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="example-default">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

but that's not valid HTML so the browser will probably convert it to this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="example-default">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

before it hits the page. Then you try to add a more invalid stuff through your `AbsenceListItemView` (i.e. `<tr>`s that aren't inside `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, or `<table>`) so the browser will try to make sense of that. Finally, you try to append:

```
    </tbody>
</table>
```

which the browser will probably convert to:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and you end up with an incomprehensible mess.

You need to treat your `<table>` as a single unit. Combine your `tableEnd` and `tableStart` into something valid:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="example-default">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then append the `AbsenceListItemView`s to the `<tbody>` in there:

```
render: function (eventName) {
    this.$el.html(this.template()); // This has both pieces.
    this.collection.each(function(model) {
        this.$('tbody').append(new AbsenceListItemView({model: model}).render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

Note a few other changes:

1. Your `model` was actually a collection so you should use `this.collection` instead of `this.model` inside the view and say `new AbsenceListView({ collection: ... })` when instantiating the view.
2. Use [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) inside the view instead of creating a new jQuery wrapped version all the time by calling `$(this.el)` over and over again. Backbone creates `this.$el` for you so you should use it.
3. Use [`this.$()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) to find this within your view's `el`, this is a shortcut for `this.$el.find(...)` that Backbone sets up for you.
4. Backbone [mixes various Underscore methods into collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you can say `this.collection.each(...)` instead of mucking around with the collection's `models` property with things like `_.each(this.collection.models, ...)`.